# Interpreting Reading dmesg error logs

Tags: 18.04

My ubuntu PC dual boot seems to randomly restart at times. At other times it works fine, but of late, it seems to be restarting randomly quite often. It's very annoying, and i"m not sure why. The core temperatures of my CPU seem fine.

Here is the log of the `dmesg | grep -i error` and was hoping if some folks could comment whether any of the following is out of the ordinary:

```
[    0.065544] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191) 
[    0.065553] ACPI Error: Ignore error and continue table load (20170831/psobject-642) 
[    0.065554] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Scope (20170831/psloop-559) 
[    0.065914] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP09.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191) 
[    0.065919] ACPI Error: Ignore error and continue table load (20170831/psobject-642) 
[    0.065920] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Scope (20170831/psloop-559) 
[    0.794326] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized. 
[    2.661688] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro 
[    4.934733] EXT4-fs (sdc2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

### Edit - Added Files as requested

- Here is [full copy of my DMESG output starting at 0](https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/1736936ce4be49f18554949fa35eea38#gistcomment-3336564).
- Here is a copy of [journalctl](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BKSpurgeon/1736936ce4be49f18554949fa35eea38/raw/5facf8b18ea6e8891dea74b43aac27f8ff207bd2/dump-of-journalctl.txt).
- Here is a copy of [syslog files](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BKSpurgeon/1736936ce4be49f18554949fa35eea38/raw/121d92442f3a462b40c97c7c8ad27aae03e40682/syslog) - the rebooting happened at around 13:17.

Comment: You need to look at logs for the seconds *before* the reboot, not after.  Dmesg logs are timestamped: [0.000000] occurs at reboot, so you're showing us information *after* the reboot, which is rarely helpful.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for the pointer. I have udpated the answer with a link to the full dmesg output starting from 0 - any pointers would be appreciated. chrs

Comment: 0 is the time of boot, you need to look *before* boot (ie. the prior session) which is impossible using `dmesg` as it only shows detail from the current boot session (not prior sessions).  You might find clues in `journalctl` (systemd journal) as it continues after reboot...

Comment: Try looking at the end of a previous dmesg: /var/log/dmesg.0. Also look at /var/log/syslog.  The most common reasons for unexpected and unlogged reboots are hardware: Overheating or dying power supplies.

Comment: @user535733 have updated the systlog and journalctl files as you have suggested.

Comment: Nothing useful in logs. Start looking up how to identify those hardware failures.

Comment: @user535733 will do. thx and appreciate the pointers.